# Confusion regarding QNET VTOL (Vertical Take off and Landing)

Tags: motor, control, control-system, pid-controller

I was reading a manual about QNET VTOL and I came across a block diagram (shown in attached snapshot).

In the explaination of diagram, manual writes that

> The VTOL device is broken down into two subsystems: **the voltage-current dynamics of the motor
> and the current position dynamics of the VTOL body**. The cascade control implemented in the VTOL
> trainer is depicted in Figure 10.2 below. A PI current controller, the inner loop, is designed to
> regulate the current inside the motor according to a desired current reference. This current
> reference is generated from the outer-loop controller: a PID compensator that controls the pitch of the VTOL trainer.

Where are the two subsytems in block diagram,i think one systems is motor represented by the one with denominator Lms+Rm,if yes how/where other system is represented?

After locating the two subsystems in block diagram, please also mention their working/aplication.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the motor control is shown in detail.  The pitch dynamics of the aircraft only show up as \$P(s)\$.

Comment: you mean all the blocks/parts in dotted/dashed rectangle represent only motor control?

Comment: Yes.  Just replace "Actuator" with "Motor" in the title for that sub-system, and the block diagram will match the text.